# Insert partially copied new record into same table

Tags: sqlite, insert

I'm fairly new to SQLite and trying to do something which seems very simply but not working.

I want to insert a new record in a table with the same OwnerID but slightly different data, a partial copy, so insert record data;

**2, 55, newdata, DARLTY**

WHERE original record data is;

**1, 55, originaldata, DARLTY**

Problem is I keep getting 'near "OwnerID": syntax error.' I'm thinking I need to get the original record values into variables somehow before inserting them into the new record but how?

This is what I have which is obviously flawed, TIA

```
    INSERT INTO MyTable
 NULL AS KeyID, OwnerID AS OwnerID, 'newdata' AS Field2, Field3 AS Field3
 WHERE Field3 LIKE '%DARL%'
 AND Field3 <> 'DARLINGTON'
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the **`SELECT`** and **`FROM`** keywords.

So your query should/could be :-

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
    SELECT null AS keyid,ownerid AS ownerid,field2 AS field2,field3 AS field3 
    FROM mytable WHERE field3 LIKE '%DARLTY%' AND field3 <> 'DARLINGTON';
```

Although the marginally simpler :-

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ownerid,field2,field3) 
    SELECT ownerid,field2,field3 
    FROM mytable WHERE field3 LIKE '%DARLTY%' AND field3 <> 'DARLINGTON';
```

Would do exactly the same.

e.g. The following (*x added to the table name for my convenience* ) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytablex ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytablex (keyid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,ownerid INTEGER,  field2 TEXT, field3 TEXT);
INSERT INTO mytablex VALUES(1,55,'newdata','DARLTY'); -- Original value
INSERT INTO mytablex (ownerid,field2,field3) 
    SELECT ownerid,field2,field3 
    FROM mytablex WHERE field3 LIKE '%DARLTY%' AND field3 <> 'DARLINGTON';
SELECT * FROM mytablex;
```

results in :-

[image]

However, **beware**, if you subsequently run the insert then you will insert more rows e.g. using the following a second time :-

```
INSERT INTO mytablex (ownerid,field2,field3) 
    SELECT ownerid,field2,field3 
    FROM mytablex WHERE field3 LIKE '%DARLTY%' AND field3 <> 'DARLINGTON';
SELECT * FROM mytablex;
```

would result in :-

[image]

and if run a third time then :-

[image]

To eliminate such duplication, you may wish to consider using :-

```
INSERT INTO mytablex (ownerid,field2,field3) SELECT ownerid,field2,field3 
    FROM mytablex 
        WHERE field3 LIKE '%DARLTY%' 
            AND field3 <> 'DARLINGTON' 
            AND (
                SELECT count() FROM mytablex WHERE field3 LIKE '%DARLTY%' AND field3 <> 'DARLINGTON'
                 ) = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to reply, everydays a school day at the moment and syntax error is not much good without some kind of suggesting help.